# Is there a function for parsing a string into a specific interpretation of it's contents?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my string: `'NE2SW15W2X8E'`

My output is:

```
[('N', 1),
('E', 2),
('S', 1),
('W', 15),
('W', 2),
('X', 8),
('E', 1)]
```

The outcome is on the following basis:
1) N does not have any number after it, so take 1 as default
2) E has a number after it so take it rather than the default number 1
3) Similarly, W and X have numbers after it so used that instead of the default.

Thanks in advance for the help, it's highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no function in Python to do that but you can write one

Comment: can you help me in that?

Comment: I have updated your title to match the question. There is no built-in function to do this, but it is relatively straightforward to do with a loop or with a regex, depending on your ability level. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @lxop I can see a loop implementation, but how would you use a regex for this?

Comment: @FarhaanPatel there is no such function, you have to write it yourself.

Comment: @hiten like Amadan has done in their answer

Comment: @lxop yeah I saw that... it’s an amazing way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find all <strike>directions</strike> uppercase letters potentially followed by zero or more numbers; if there's no numbers, use 1.

```
[(d, int(n) if n else 1) for d, n in re.findall('([A-Z])(\d*)', 'NE2SW15W2X8E')]
```

EDIT: didn't see an `X` there